# Set the Actor's sprite to the default

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having troubles with my `Actor` objects. When I click on the `Button Actor`, I want it to switch the `Screen`. When I do this, and I return to the last screen, the button that I clicked is still being hovered until I move my mouse again:

[image]

The code that I have for it:

```
// Load Game
textButtons[1].addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        // GameState is a subclass of Screen,
        // GameStateManager helps me to manage my GameStates.
        game.setGameState(GameStateManager.get("screenLoadGame"));
    }
});
```

I've tried to "trick" it to fix this, by using the `keyUp` method, and doing the following:

```
@Override
public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
    int[] mousePos = { Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY() };
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(0, 0);
    stage.act(1);
    game.setGameState(GameStateManager.get("screenLoadGame"));
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(mousePos[0], mousePos[1]);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

In the end, I want to be able to switch from one `Screen` back to the `Main Menu Screen`, and have the button as its default sprite. Is there a way to set an `Actor's (Button's) Sprite`?

**NOTE:** For the sprites (in the Json file) The up/down is how "Start New Game" shows it. The over sprite is when it has the gray background (like "Load Game").

Comment: For now, I have decided to just `dispose` of `screenMenu` when I leave it, and I'll reload everything when I go back to it (it isn't intensive at all).

Answer (score 2):

Use a ChangeListener instead of a ClickListener. This will also allow your buttons to behave like buttons are expected to (if you click down and move your cursor off the button before releasing, it won't fire).

You can use a single ChangeListener for many buttons quite easily to keep your code tidy.

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        if (actor == startNewGameButton){
            startNewGame();
        } else if (actor == loadGameButton){
            loadGame();
        } else if (actor == creditsButton){
            showCreditsScreen();
        } 
    }
};
```

And then to add it to a button:

```
startNewGameButton.addListener(changeListener);
```